# Ionic Android Release build kills HTTPS request

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework, ionic2

The problem with building my app is that when I build it with

```
cordova clean android
cordova build --release android 

+ sign + zipalign
```

the app fails to process any http / https request. 
When I build with

```
cordova build --debug android
```

the requests work, but I can not upload it to the app store because it's a debug build.

I would like to compare both final builds to identify the culprit. How can I compare the now binary AndroidManifest.xml files for instance? I found this post, yet I can not make any sense out of it for myself.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you get on the console, when running the release apk?

Generally, instead of running

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

you should run

```
ionic cordova build android --release --prod
```

You can also open the platforms/android directory with Android Studio and run it from there (to have a clearer Logging output)